# how to disable vim autocomplete popup for plain text files?

Tags: vim, plugins

After literally days of tweaking, I think I got vim's autocomplete (omnicomplete + [Acp plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879)) to work acceptably. But the annoying thing is that it is still enabled for plain text files so I would have to type :DisableAcp for README or plain text files. How do I add logic to my vimrc so that if it detects an empty filetype it disables the Acp on startup?

here is what I wrote:

```
if &filetype == ""
     let g:acp_enableStartup = 0
endif
```

but this disables Acp on start up for all files.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd WinEnter README,*.txt :DisableAcp
autocmd WinLeave README,*.txt :EnableAcp
```

---

#### Update:

```
autocmd WinEnter * :if &ft=='text' | DisableAcp | else | EnableAcp | endif
```

Comment: After reading the question and variable names I believe it should be `:DisableAcp`, not `let g:acp_enableStartup`.

Comment: Thanks, this is great but how about plain old text files that don't have an extension and is not a README? That's the part that I am struggling with.

Comment: so far so good... will test for a few more days and then come back to see if this works for all the cases I encounter! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The function/method is `:AcpDisable`, not `:DisableAcp`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the logic after not knowing why vim doesn't honor my

```
autocmd Filetype * | if &omnifunc=="" | call acp#disable() | endif
```

so I did this:

```
let g:acp_EnableAtStartup = 0
autocmd FileType python call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType ncl call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType javascript call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType html call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType css call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType xml call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType php call acp#enable()
autocmd FileType c call acp#enable()
```

and this works.
Thanks for your help.